# Are there Quick Reference Cards for all SharePoint functions?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, help

Does SharePoint 2013 Help offer Additional resources: Quick Reference Cards for all of SharePoint's functions? I can't seem to find any for Lists from the help section. However I can for Librarys.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.customguide.com/cheat_sheets/sharepoint-2013-quick-reference.pdf

Comment: Yes. I notice Microsoft offers from very nice Word tutorials for SharePoint functions but not others. They are called Quick Reference Cards.

Comment: Quick Reference Card isn't a Microsoft or a SharePoint term. They're often also called cheatsheets. It's something you'll find for a lot of software.